# Set value of TextBox after function execution asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I try to make a site with a asp.net web application, but I can't continue because, I can not set the value of TextBox to "finish" after the execution of a function file download.

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = "start";
            }
        }

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";            
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=print_ordre.pdf");
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/print_ordre.pdf"));
        //Response.End();

        TextBox1.Text = "finish";
    }
```

I await your help ...

Comment: You cannot download a file and update the page at the same time. Why do you want to show a message, because a user already know that the file is downloaded successfully.

Comment: You cannot return two content type in the response of single request. Updating value of your textbox returns HTML response but you have set the content type as pdf.